# Adding Subscripts to Facets labels in R

Tags: r, facet

I am plotting data with many variables using facets and would like to label the title of each facet using its variable however some variables have subscripts such as NO[3], SO[4].

I tried the following code but they turn out the same:

```r
NewDat1$facets = factor(NewDat1$Parameter, labels = c( " Alkalinity",  
"Ca (CaCO3)","Cl(mg/l),", "Conductivity (mS/m)","Cu (mg/l)","F (mg/l)",
"Fe (mg/l)","K (mg/l","Mg (CaCO3)"," Mn(mg/l)","Na (mg/l)",
expression("NO[3] (mg/l)"), "pH",expression (" SiO[2](mg/l)"),
expression("SO[4] (mg/l)"),"TDS (TDS Calculated)",
"Turbidity (NTU)","Zn (mg/l)"))

ggplot(na.omit(NewDat1), aes(Year, Value, color = Location)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()+ 
  facet_wrap(~facets, scales = "free_y" )
```

[image: RESULTS]

```
NewDat1 <- structure(list(Year = c(1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003), 
Value = c(8.06666666666667, 8.15, 8.3, 8.38333333333333, 
8.05, 8.36666666666667), Parameter = c("pH", "pH", "pH", 
"pH", "pH", "pH"), Location = c("Roshpinah", "Roshpinah", 
"Roshpinah", "Roshpinah", "Roshpinah", "Roshpinah"), facets = structure(c(13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c(" Alkalinity", "Ca (CaCO3)", 
"Cl (mg/l),", "Conductivity (mS/m)", "Cu (mg/l)", "F (mg/l)", 
"Fe (mg/l)", "K (mg/l", "Mg (CaCO3)", " Mn (mg/l)", "Na (mg/l)", 
"NO[3] (mg/l)", "pH", " SiO[2] (mg/l)", "SO[4] (mg/l)", "TDS (TDS Calculated)", 
"Turbidity (NTU)", "Zn (mg/l)"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have all your factor labels as strings rather than expressions and use `labeller = label_parsed`. Note that your sample data only contains a single level of the faceting variable, so I have had to fake the levels and use `drop = FALSE` inside `facet_grid` to show this in action:

```r
NewDat1$facets = factor(NewDat1$Parameter, levels = c( "Alkalinity",  
    "Ca (CaCO3)",
    "Cl(mg/l)", 
    "Conductivity (mS/m)",
    "Cu (mg/l)",
    "F (mg/l)",
    "Fe (mg/l)",
    "K (mg/l)",
    "Mg (CaCO3)",
    " Mn(mg/l)",
    "Na (mg/l)",
    "NO[3] (mg/l)", 
    "pH",
    "SiO[2] (mg/l)",
    "SO[4] (mg/l)",
    "TDS (TDS~Calculated)",
    "Turbidity (NTU)",
    "Zn (mg/l)")) 

ggplot(na.omit(NewDat1), aes(Year, Value, color = Location)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ facets, scales = "free_y", drop = FALSE,
             labeller = label_parsed)
```

[image]

Comment: what does the `rep (13, 6)` in the code do? I tried this and only the first variable was replicated throughout all cells.

Comment: @Ndahambelela that was only to get the code working with your sample data - you don't need to do this. I have updated to a version that should work with your own data set, though there are a few typos that you may need to fix in your own code: `"Cl(mg/l),"` shouldn't have the comma in it, `"K (mg/l"` needs a closing bracket, and you will need to put a tilde `~` into TDS Calculated as in my example. You will need to change these in your data set itself to get the factoring code to work properly.

Comment: when I run the first part of the code, mMost of the variables become NA. I copied the exact code you have here. Is there something wrong with my data perhaps?

Comment: @Ndahambelela probably - you need to make sure that values in the `Parameter` column in your data frame are identical to those that you write in the factor levels. It's difficult to show you how to do this without having all your data.

Comment: I understand now. How do I use the `dput` for the whole data without having a large list to past?

Comment: @Ndahambelela can you post in somewhere as csv? Dropbox etc?